# Create a TikZ node without displaying it yet

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using a lot of nodes in a big matrix of nodes, and i'd like to separate the creation of the nodes from their placing in the matrix. A syntax close to :

```
init (node1) ...;
init (node2) ...;
init (node3) ...;
init (node4) ...;

matrix[matrix of nodes]{
    (node1) & (node2) \\
    (node3) & (node4) \\
};
```

Does this exist in TikZ ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option nesting code in definitions, you can also place images according to the predefined size and separation of nodes and of course some random ducks.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,matrix}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Global config
        baseline=(current  bounding  box.center),
        scale=0.25,
        >=latex,
        line width=1pt,
        %Styles
        Brace/.style={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                brace,
                raise=-7pt
            }
        },
        Matrix/.style={
            matrix of nodes,
            text height=2.5ex,
            text depth=0.75ex,
            text width=3.25ex,
            align=center,
            left delimiter=\{,
            right delimiter=\},
            column sep=5pt,
            row sep=5pt,
            %nodes={draw=black!10}, % Uncoment to see the square nodes.
            nodes in empty cells,
        }
        ]
        
        \def\nodA#1{\node[draw,circle,inner sep=0,fill=green!50!cyan]{#1};}
        \def\nodB#1{\node[draw,rectangle,inner sep=0,fill opacity=0.2,fill=blue, text opacity=1]{#1};}
        \def\nodC#1{\node[draw,shape=star,inner sep=0,fill=lime!70!blue]{#1};}
        \def\nodD#1{\node[inner sep=0,label={[label distance=-5,scale=0.5]#1}]{\includegraphics[height=2.5ex]{example-image-a}};}
        \def\nodE#1{\tikz\shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.3]\node{#1};}
        
        
        \matrix[Matrix] at (0,0) (M){ % Matrix contents  
            \nodA{1}& \nodB{2} & \nodC{3} & \nodE{4} \\
            \nodB{5}& \nodC{6} & \nodE{7} & \nodD{8} \\
            \nodC{9}& \nodE{10} & \nodD{11} & \nodE{12} \\
            \nodE{9}& \nodD{10} & \nodE{11} & \nodE{12} \\
        };
        

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```